# Expand div with fixed width

Tags: css

How do I expand the div`#wrapper` outside its parent by its child item's width`.item` like the image below?

[image]

I have tried `translate` but the result is not ideal. The hardest part is that I cannot programmatically expand it with the item's width, but hard code it with translate like `90px` which causes a problem when the screen is resized (please use the developer tool to resize and you will get my point).

I cannot use `position: absolute;` because there are some elements before the `#wrapper`.

Below is my try:

```css
#main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  height: 600px;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

#first,
#second {
  width: 50%;
}

#first {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 30px;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  transform: translateX(90px);
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="first">
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
#main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  height: 600px;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

#first,
#second {
  width: 50%;
}

#first {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 30px;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  margin-right:-66%;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="first">
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
  </div>
</div>
```